# ¿Como usar la función csrf() en un controlador?

Tags: laravel, formularios, tokens

Tengo un problema con esto.

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.7 y necesito consumir una API que por cosas del destino no puedo utilizar en esta aplicación.

Así que lo que hice fue mandar a llamar los método espesificos de la aplicación que consume el API. Y todo funciona bien.

Ejemplo:

```
herader('Location: https://midominio/ruta_que_consume_el_api?parametro=identifica_de_donde_la_llamo');
```

El problema empieza cuando mando la respuesta con sus datos a la nueva aplicación.

Lo que hago es crear un formulario que se auto envia a mi nueva aplicación. Con todos los datos que proveyó el API.

Ejemplo:

```
Public function metodo_que_se_ejecuta_cuando_el_api_responde(Request $request){

   ?>
            <form action='https://nueva_aplicación/metodo2' method='post'>

                 <Input type='hidden' name='data' value=<?php print_r($request->all()) ?>''>

                 // Este es el problema dado que este token caduca.

                <Input type='hidden' name='_token' value='el token que tiene el usuario pasado de forma manual'>

           </form>

           <script>
             document.form.submit();
          </script>

   <?php
}
```

Y esta información la proceso en mi nueva aplicación.

Todo funciona bien hasta que el token caduca y por consiguiente mi aplicación me manda a la página de error 433 sesión caducada.

Se me ocurre mandar igual el token en la primera petición pero quiero saber si hay otra forma que no sea la de desactivar el csfr token

Comment: ¿Por qué hay html adentro de la función de un controlador?

Comment: Porque es la única forma que encontré para hacer una petición post, no encontré métodos en php que me ayudaran hacer la petición. lo unico que puedo hacer con php es el header(). pero genera una petición get y no me sirve.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas curl de php?

Comment: No conozco la librería o función mañana la reviso y veo que tal, por lo pronto lo hice como comente mas abajo y se soluciono mi problema. Pero se que es mala practica tener HTML en mi controlador.

Comment: Así es, es una mala práctica, mañana te pongo en ejemplo con curl, también hay una librería para Laravel que se llama Guzzle Http, también te puede ayudar a consumir APIs.

Comment: gracias si termine utilizando curl

Answer (score 1):

Con `curl` de `php` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
      $un_dato = '1';
      $datos = array('un_dato' => $un_dato);
      $fields = http_build_query($datos);
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "http://url.com",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache"
          ),
      ));

      $response = curl_exec($curl);
      $err = curl_error($curl);

      curl_close($curl);
```

Desconozco que es lo que te pide la API que estás consultando y lo que devuelve pero puedes hacer un `dd($response)` para ver lo que te está regresando.

También existe una librería para laravel llamada "Guzzle", te dejo la documentación:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Se que una posible solucion es:

```
// ruta que llama al api
header('Location: https//dominio/?var1=algo&token=token');
```

En el metodo que se ejecuta para llamar el api

```
session_star();
$_SESSION['token'] = $_GET['token'];
```

Obviamente con su lógica de comprobación de variables.

En el metodo de respuesta

```
session_star();
if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
     ?>
        <form action='https://nueva_aplicación/metodo2' method='post'>

             <Input type='hidden' name='data' value=<?php print_r($request->all()) ?>''>

             // Este es el problema dado que este token caduca.

            <Input type='hidden' name='_token' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['token']'>

       </form>

       <script>
         document.form.submit();
      </script>
    <?php
}
```